# Different template for different categories in Magento

Tags: layout, magento, categories

I want to display subcategories under artist category in one layout and design and other categories in another layout and design in Magento 1.4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use static blocks.

1) Create phtml file in **/template/catalog/navigation**

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

2) Create static block "Subcategories"

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation"  template="catalog/navigation/subcategory.phtml"}}
```

3) Assign static block for needed category ("Display Settings" tab -> Display Mode = Static block only and select CMS Block "Subcategories")

Answer (score 7):

In the web admin, under Manage Categories, select the categories you want to be different and navigate to the Custom Design tab.  You can enter layout updates or select alternative skin/themes.

Comment: @JonathanDay 

I use template on specific category. its not showing on frontpage.
i call this template. Path is correct. but now showing.

Custom Layout Update:
`{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/product/viewed_product.phtml"}}`

Comment: Excellent advise, you saved my day.